# How to customize Webpack error overlay output message?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, npm, webpack

I want to customize the error overlay output message so that it won't show any paths to loaders, like in the image:

[image: example overlay output]

So how can I get rid of the line similar to the above from the overlay output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I've done some reverse engineering work and found out that it's `webpack-dev-server` itself which is displaying it and it cannot be edited by any setting/option. So I had to do some dirty hack which simply extends overlay's `showMessage()` method and removes the fist two lines (which contain paths to loaders). My dirty workaround looks like this:

```
const overlay = require('webpack-dev-server/client/overlay');
const show = overlay.showMessage;
overlay.showMessage = function (messages) {

  const newMessages = messages.map(
    msg => msg
      .split('\n')
      .slice(2)
      .join('\n')
  );

  show(newMessages);
};
```